# Reading binary file with text header of variable length

Tags: python, file-io

How do I skip a header with a specific number of lines, and then read the remainder of the data which is binary?

I just need to parse out the file, some of which is text, the other is binary. I have access to the number of lines in the header, and the data in binary following is variable. I cannot use fseek to skip the header as I do not know it's size, but I can just read the number of lines to skip it

Comment: What do you mean by "the remainder of the data is binary"? A binary number, or do you need to read the data in binary mode i.e. get bytes?

Comment: Get bytes.  Sorry, this was simpler than I realized. I just needed to parse out the file, some of which is text, the other is binary. I have access to the number of lines in the header, and the data in binary following is variable. I cannot use fseek to skip the header as I do not know it's size, but I can just read the number of lines to skip it.

Comment: Your last comment should have been an edit to the question, because it is essential information to understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
def readsomelines(fh,nlines):
    for i in range(nlines):
        yield fh.readline()

with open("asd","rb") as my_file:
    header = list(readsomelines(my_file,3))
    binary = my_file  # myfile should be starting on 4th line now
```

Im curious if you actually tried anything before coming here and asking?

Comment: Thanks! I was using f.seek() and to move the pointer ahead in bytes. I did not know that  the file after the header lines were scanned just included the binary info.